# CSS Font Size .5 Increments

Tags: css, font-size

In CSS are you allowed to use .5 increments i.e

```
font-size: 8.5pt;
```

Can't see the difference between     font-size: 8pt and font-size: 8.5pt

Comment: In my experience, this varies from browser to browser. Best to stick to integers, or sprite the text.

Comment: A pt is 1/72 of an inch, so when you're doing half of that, the difference is very negligible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Point values are really only for print CSS.

Quoting Chris C:

> A point is a unit of measurement used for real-life ink-on-paper
>   typography. 72pts = one inch. One inch = one real-life inch
>   like-on-a-ruler. Not an inch on a screen, which is totally arbitrary
>   based on resolution.

Source: http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

The W3C Tips page suggest avoiding them for screen:

> The so-called absolute units (cm, mm, in, pt and pc) mean the same in
>   CSS as everywhere else. A length expressed in any of these will appear
>   as exactly that size (within the precision of the hardware and
>   software). They are not recommended for use on screen, because screen
>   sizes vary so much. A big screen may be 60cm (24in), a small, portable
>   screen is maybe only 8cm. And you don't look at them from the same
>   distance.

Source: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: Great answer! You can see here that using "pt" still works, its just too small to see http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/ZvUbd/1/

Answer (score 2):

A half point is a very small amount. Without zooming your screen, you likely will never see the difference. Nonetheless, the software IS calculating it and displaying it as best as your resolution allows.

Answer (score -1):

When you do a .5 increment while using pt. that may or may not be big enough for the browser to render larger. And then every browser renders text slightly different.

Comment: The question is asking about `pt`, not `em`. What you're describing is for the `em` unit.

Comment: Although you should use a different measure type to get different results. Pixels are normally used in the world of CSS fonts.