# Rationale behind font sizes in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-size

Here are the header sizes from `bootstrap.css`:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 38.5px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 31.5px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24.5px;
}
```

I was surprised by the fact that these sizes are fractional (half-integers), which suggests that their precision is at least `0.25px` (less than 1%).

How do web designers arrive at such sizes? Are they obtained by some scientific process, some calculation perhaps? Or do people simply stare at their site, playing with sizes until it feels right? How can a designer convince his teammate that it really ought to be `31.5px` and not just `31px`?

Comment: I was also wondering when I say those units, I was like, well! how would a screen display half pixel? if its possible, then they are two pixels right? definitely not two half pixels.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093688/css-font-size-5-increments.

Comment: @SathishManohar: actually, that didn't surprise me that much. There may be various dimensions that are proportional to the base font size, and there you can observe the difference. But what I really don't understand is how they came up with these values.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They haven’t exactly specified font size 31.5px, instead they specified base font size and coefficients for headings, see [code](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/less):

```
// file: variables.less
@baseFontSize:          14px;

// file: type.less
h1 { font-size: @baseFontSize * 2.75; } // ~38px
h2 { font-size: @baseFontSize * 2.25; } // ~32px
h3 { font-size: @baseFontSize * 1.75; } // ~24px
h4 { font-size: @baseFontSize * 1.25; } // ~18px
h5 { font-size: @baseFontSize; }
h6 { font-size: @baseFontSize * 0.85; } // ~12px
```

Users of bootstrap are free to customize base font size, if they want to, in their custom builds; font size in heading will change automatically and proportionally, that’s the point.

Comment: Ah. I forgot that the CSS code is generated. But why didn't they use relative font sizes in CSS? (Like `font-size: 275%;` if I'm not mistaken about the syntax.)

Comment: If you specify `font-size: 275%;` it means 2.75 of the font size in parent element, and you don’t know what is the parent element or what its font size is. Bootstrap uses another approach where font sizes are related to the base font size but nevertheless are fixed and independent of parent element’s font size.